# Can I insert multiple setTimeouts in a setInterval?

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, setinterval

I just started learning JavaScript and right now, I'm making a virtual traffic light that lights up red, green and orange. I would like to make a loop by adding a `setInterval` to the outside. Is this possible or should i use some other method of making a loop. I tried making a a `for(;;){}` but this causes an error and the webpage never loads. Here is my current code.

```js
var red = document.getElementById("circleRed");
var orange = document.getElementById('circleOrange')
var green = document.getElementById('circleGreens');
    
setInterval(
    
  setTimeout( function(){
    red.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }, 2000),
    
   setTimeout(function(){
      green.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      red.style.backgroundColor = "black";
   }, 5000),
    
    setTimeout(function(){
      orange.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
      green.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    }, 10000),
    
    5000);
```

```css
#circleRed, #circleGreens, #circleOrange {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: "black";
}

.back {
    width: 60px;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: black;
}
    
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <div id="circleRed">
  </div>
  <div id="circleOrange">
  </div>
  <div id="circleGreens">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cal your all `setTimeout` function in a `loop` function. And call this loop function with `setInterval`.
Note : I also changed some of the color changing sections in your code .

jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/zgdx5xan/

```js
var red = document.getElementById("circleRed");
var orange = document.getElementById('circleOrange')
var green = document.getElementById('circleGreens');

loop();
setInterval(loop,11000);

function loop(){
 console.log("loop started")
  setTimeout( function(){
    red.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    orange.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    green.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    console.log("red opened")
  }, 2000);

   setTimeout(function(){
    green.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    red.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    console.log("green opened")
  }, 5000);

  setTimeout(function(){
    orange.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    green.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    red.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    console.log("orange opened")    
  }, 10000);
}
```

```css
#circleRed, #circleGreens, #circleOrange {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: "black";
}



.back{
  width: 60px;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
 
   <div class="back">
    <div id="circleRed">

    </div>
    <div id="circleOrange">

    </div>
    <div id="circleGreens">

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

setInterval, like setTimeout also requires a function to be passed as a first argument, in that function you would then be able to compose your setTimeout's.

```
var red = document.getElementById("circleRed");
var orange = document.getElementById('circleOrange');
var green = document.getElementById('circleGreens');

setInterval(function () {
  red.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  orange.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  green.style.backgroundColor = "black";

  setTimeout(function () {
    red.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }, 2000);

  setTimeout(function () {
    green.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    red.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  }, 5000);

  setTimeout(function () {
    orange.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    green.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  }, 8000);
}, 10000)
```

I have adjusted your timings a little as your final timeout was longer than the interval. You can see this working here: [codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OOQyMK)

Answer (score 1):

Think to the traffic lights as an object with 3 states, redOn, greenOn and OrangeOn. You need to loop through states, so starting from redOn pass the next one in the sequence and reset in the last one. I think setInterval here is not required as it cause you to care about the total time that's irrelevant.

```js
var red = document.getElementById("circleRed");
var orange = document.getElementById('circleOrange')
var green = document.getElementById('circleGreens');

var redFor = 200 //2000
var greenFor = 500 //5000
var orangeFor = 1000 //10000

let redOn = function(next) {
  red.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  orange.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  setTimeout(next, redFor);
}

let orangeOn = function(next) {
  orange.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  green.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  setTimeout(next, orangeFor);
}

let greenOn = function(next) {
  green.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  red.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  setTimeout(next, greenFor);
}

let start = function() {
  redOn(function() {
    greenOn(function() {
      orangeOn(start)
    })
  })
}

start()
```

```css
#circleRed,
#circleGreens,
#circleOrange {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: "black";
}

.back {
  width: 60px;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="object2.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="back">
    <div id="circleRed"></div>
    <div id="circleOrange"></div>
    <div id="circleGreens"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="objects1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative implementation with equal times for every light.

```js
var red    = document.getElementById('circleRed');
var orange = document.getElementById('circleOrange');
var green  = document.getElementById('circleGreens');

/* Set an array with the desired order to turn on lights */
var lights = [red, green, orange];

function open(light) {
    light.classList.add('opened');
}

function close(light) {
    light.classList.remove('opened');
}


function change() {
    close(lights[i]);
    i = (i + 1) % lights.length;
    open(lights[i]);
}

/* Start */
var i = 0;
open(lights[i]);
setInterval(change, 1000);
```

```css
.circle {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 5px;
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: opacity 200ms;
}

.circle.opened {
    opacity: 1;
}

#circleRed {
    background-color: red;
}

#circleOrange {
    background-color: orange;
}

#circleGreens {
    background-color: green;
}


.back {
    width: 60px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <div id="circleRed" class="circle"></div>
  <div id="circleOrange" class="circle"></div>
  <div id="circleGreens" class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

**Explanation:**

Instead of changing the background color of every circle from black to its own color to light up the circle or viceversa to switch off, in my example all circles have their respective color (red, green or orange) faded to (almost) transparent with `opacity: 0.2` (originally I used 0, but I think it looks better with 0.2) See: [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity).

So, all elements with class `.circle` have:

```
.circle {
    /* Other properties */
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Then, I use a class called `opened` to turn the opacity to 1 making the circle visible.

```
.circle.opened {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Since `.circle.opened` has higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than just `.circle`, opacity: 1 prevails on those elements having both classes (`circle` and `opened`).

To add or remove the class `opened` from a light item I use two simple functions `open` and `close` that manipulate the element's [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). **This is important**. In general it's more recommended to define element's properties (styles) in classes and use JS to add or remove this classes to alter the element that to modify element's styles directly with JS.

So, it's cleaner and more recommended to do:

```
/* CSS */
.red { background-color: red }

/* Javascript */
var element = document.getElementById('#element_ID');
element.classList.add('red');
```

than:

```
/* Javascript */
var element = document.getElementById('#element_ID');
element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Even though it may seem easier this second way.

To change the lights, I made an array with the elements in the desired order:

```
var lights = [red, green, orange];
```

As you can see, every element of the lights [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is one of the circles, we already stored in variables with `document.getElementById()` (if you're not familiar with arrays, dedicate some time to read and understand what they are and how they work. They're one of the most basic data structures in any programming language, so it's important to master them.)

To start, I initiate a global variable to `0` (`var i = 0`) and I light up the first light with:

```
open(lights[i]);
```

Since `i` equals 0, `lights[i]`, so `lights[0]` is `red` (In JS, as in most languages, arrays start counting their elements from 0). This way, `open(lights[i])` is the same as `open(red)`.

Then I do a `setInterval(change, 1000)` so every second the function `change()` is called. And what does this `change` function do?

Basically:

```
// Turn off the current light
close(lights[i]);

// Increment i, so that lights[i] points to the next element... 
i = (i + 1) % lights.length;

// Turn on this next element
open(lights[i]);
```

The rarest thing here may be the increment. Why do I do `i = (i + 1) % lights.length` instead of just `i++`.

If I do `i++` after successive calls to `change`, `i` will be: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6... so, when I try to access `lights[i]` I'll get an error, because there is no element in positions 3, 4, 5... of the `lights` array.

I need my sequence to be: 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2...

How do I get this desired sequence instead of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6... ?

Maybe a more understandable way could be:

```
i++;
if (i > 2) {
    i = 0;
}
```

But I'm using the [Remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator (`%`) to achieve the same effect.

I hope this helps!

---

And another one with easily configurable duration for every light:

```js
var lights = {
    red: {
        node: document.getElementById('circleRed'),
        duration: 4000,
    },
    green: {
        node: document.getElementById('circleGreens'),
        duration: 2000,
    },
    orange: {
        node: document.getElementById('circleOrange'),
        duration: 800,
    }
};

var order = ['red', 'green', 'orange'];


function open(light) {
    light.node.classList.add('opened');
}

function close(light) {
    light.node.classList.remove('opened');
}

function change() {
    close(lights[order[i]]);
    i = (i + 1) % order.length;
    open(lights[order[i]]);
    setTimeout(change, lights[order[i]].duration);
}

/* Start */
var i = 0;
open(lights[order[i]]);

setTimeout(change, lights[order[i]].duration);
```

```css
.circle {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 200ms;
}

.circle.opened {
    opacity: 1;
}

#circleRed {
    background-color: red;
}

#circleOrange {
    background-color: orange;
}

#circleGreens {
    background-color: green;
}


.back {
    width: 60px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <div id="circleRed" class="circle"></div>
  <div id="circleOrange" class="circle"></div>
  <div id="circleGreens" class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but im not yet familiar with most of the syntax you used. I was looking for a more simpler way.

Comment: You're welcome Danny. I'll try to add more comments to my first example (the easiest one) to help you understand it. I think it's a good one because it uses some basic elements of JS that is important to understand. :)

Comment: Hey @DannyArcher, I added a better explanation of my first algorithm. I hope it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

put all `setTimeout( function(){})` in one function, then it will work

> Note: to make `setInterval` work properly, the milliseconds must be at least the total of `setTimeout` functions.

also you forgot to set the `orange` to black when the `red` is appearing.

```js
var red = document.getElementById("circleRed");
var orange = document.getElementById('circleOrange')
var green = document.getElementById('circleGreens');
    
setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 17000);
    function myTimer() {
  setTimeout( function(){
    red.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    orange.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  }, 2000),
    
   setTimeout(function(){
      green.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      red.style.backgroundColor = "black";
   }, 5000),
    
    setTimeout(function(){
      orange.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
      green.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    }, 10000)
    }
    myTimer();
```

```css
#circleRed, #circleGreens, #circleOrange {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: "black";
}

.back {
    width: 60px;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: black;
}
    
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <div id="circleRed">
  </div>
  <div id="circleOrange">
  </div>
  <div id="circleGreens">
  </div>
</div>
```